# git pull doesn't apply deletions in kubuntu /var/www/html folder

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, permission-denied

It fails with **warning: unable to unlink ...  Permission denied**

Order of operations:

Deleted some files, added the deleted files to staged files.

```
# On 1st local remote repository:*
git commit -m "deletion of folder with files"

# pushed to remote repository
git push origin branchName

# On local repository
git pull
```

gives the error: **warning: unable to unlink ...  Permission denied**

I see that the files were not deleted.
Maybe it's related to the fact that repository is in `/var/wwww/html` ?
Usually i make changes with sudo there.
It seems also that change was applied in index after running:

```
git log -1
```

How to correctly apply this deletion by *git pull* ?
Running *git pull* now returns

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: You also need to tell git that you removed the files (with: `git rm some-files`) before doing the commit.

Comment: i have deleted the files on disk, the change was tracked, i have added it to staged files and commited

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is operating system permissions.  It has nothing to do with git.  If  you look at your git status for that repo, you will likely see the files in /var/www/html as new untracked files as git thinks you've already deleted them.  I would recommend finding a user that has the appropriate permissions and deleting them manually, or running something like the following:

```
sudo git reset --hard && git clean -fdx .
```

WARNING: This command will delete any non-tracked files and reset any tracked changes.

Comment: thanks for your response. running git status doesn't display the files as new untracked files